# DIFxApp fails to copy catalog file specified in "CatalogFile.NTx86" in INF

Tags: wix

I want to make installer for driver.
I use Wix and DifxApp extension, but the driver is installed without certification.
It is failed to copy catalog file according to setupapi.log.
How to write WXS to install with certification?

Driver package is specified in WXS as below.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
    <Component Id="MyDrver" Guid="MY-GUID">
        <Difxapp:Driver
            AddRemovePrograms="no"
            DeleteFiles="yes"
            ForceInstall="yes"
            Legacy="no"
            PlugAndPlayPrompt="no"
            Sequence="1"/>
        <File Id="MyDrver_INF" Name="MyDrver.inf" Source="Driver\MyDrver.inf" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" Checksum="yes" />
        <File Id="MyDrver_CAT" Name="MyDrver.cat" Source="Driver\MyDriver_amd64.cat" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no"  DiskId="1" Checksum="yes" />
        <File Id="MyDrver_SYS" Name="MyDrver.sys" Source="Driver\MyDrver.sys" Vital="yes" KeyPath="no"  DiskId="1" Checksum="yes" />
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Catalog file is specified in INF as below.

```
CatalogFile.NTx86  = MyDriver_x86.cat
CatalogFile.NTIA64 = MyDriver_ia64.cat
CatalogFile.NTAMD64 = MyDriver_amd64.cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name="MyDrver.cat"` in the MyDrver_CAT File actually renames the file that you are installing to MyDrver.cat. Omitting the "Name" attribute will automatically name the file the same as the file defined in the Source attribute (MyDriver_amd64.cat).

I assume your driver is failing to install because the inf file defines the CAT file with a specific name that does not exist in your installation since you rename that file to something else.

Comment: Installation with certification succeeded completely by omitting the "Name" attribute.  I didn't understand about the "Name" attribute.  Thanks a lot.